# Biogeme or NLOGIT for developing ICLV

Tags: python

I try to use python biogeme for developing Integrated Choice and Latent Variable Models(ICLV).

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_possible_to_develop_Integrated_Choice_and_Latent_Variable_Models_ICLV_with_stata_or_R

As you can see above, some people said that ICLV can be developed by python biogeme and NLOGIT.

Biogeme homepage offers source code for integrating latent variables to Discrete Choice Analysis. I ran the source code but I failed with Syntax Error.

http://biogeme.epfl.ch/examples/latent/pandas/05latentChoiceFull.py

There is an error in the following part of the source code downloaded from the link above.

```
import biogeme.database as db
```

I'll attach a picture with an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf3Y9.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem with python biogeme? Or can you tell me how to developing ICLV with NLOGIT? I already read NLOGIT REFERENCE 6 GUIDEBOOK but still don't know how to implement structural equation in NLOGIT.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a Python version issue---the f-string syntax was [introduced in Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Are you using Python 3.6 or 3.7?